# How to use apply with MultiIndex Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this situation:

[image]

I'd like to use apply and add a column 'w' to each first level using the second level of columns.
Result:

```
def some_math(x,y,z):
     return x + y - z

df['w'] = df.apply(some_math)
```

Wish result:

[image]

Comment: Please edit you code and add lines to create the DataFrame so people can simply cut and paste it in their editor and try to give you the correct answer without the need to waste time recreating the DataFrame from images.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using reshaping and eval:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,3,2,1,2,1,3],[4,5,6,6,5,4,5,4,6]], 
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[*'ABC'],[*'xyz']]))

df_out  = df.stack(0).eval('w=x+y-z').unstack().swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   A           B           C         
   w  x  y  z  w  x  y  z  w  x  y  z
0  0  1  2  3  4  3  2  1  0  2  1  3
1  3  4  5  6  7  6  5  4  3  5  4  6
```